# Product sales by month - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

I just created a small data warehouse with the following details.

Fact Table

1. Sales

Dimensions

1. Supplier
2. Products
3. Time (Range is one year)
4. Stores

I want to query which product has the max sales by month, I mean the output to be like

```
Month - Product Code - Num_Of_Items
JAN      xxxx            xxxxx
FEB      xxxx            xxxxx
```

I tried the following query

```
with product_sales as(
SELECT dd.month,
  fs.p_id,
  dp.title,
 SUM(number_of_items) Num
FROM fact_sales fs
INNER JOIN dim_products dp
ON fs.p_id = dp.p_id
INNER JOIN dim_date dd
ON dd.date_id = fs.date_id
GROUP BY dd.month,
  fs.p_id,
  dp.title
)
select distinct month,movie_id,max(num) 
from product_sales 
group by movie_id,title, month;
```

Instead of max of 12 rows, I am having 132 records. I need guidance with this. Thanks.

Comment: If you need one line "per month" why would you **GROUP BY** anything else but just the month?

Comment: I think if we use aggregate functions then we need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things about your query that don't make sense, such as:

- Where does `movie_id` come from?
- What is `from abc`? Should it be `from product_sales`?

That said, if you need the maximum product sales by month *and you need to include the product code* (or movie ID or whatever), you need an analytical query. Yours would go something like this:

```
WITH product_sales AS (
  SELECT
    dd.month,
    fs.p_id,
    dp.title,
   SUM(number_of_items) Num,
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dd.month ORDER BY SUM(number_of_items) DESC) NumRank
  FROM fact_sales fs
  INNER JOIN dim_products dp ON fs.p_id = dp.p_id
  INNER JOIN dim_date dd ON dd.date_id = fs.date_id
  GROUP BY dd.month, fs.p_id, dp.title
)
SELECT month, p_id, title, num
FROM product_sales
WHERE NumRank = 1
```

Note that if there's a tie for top sales in any month, this query will show all top sales for the month. In other words, if product codes `AAAA` and `BBBB` are tied for top sales in January, the query results will have a January row for both products.

If you want just one row per month even if there's a tie, use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK()`, but note that `ROW_NUMBER` will arbitrarily pick a winner unless you define a tie-breaker. For example, to have the lowest `p_id` be the tie-breaker, define the `NumRank` column like this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  PARTITION BY dd.month
  ORDER BY SUM(number_of_items) DESC, p_id
) NumRank
```

Comment: Really sorry . Changed query a bit after pasting.

Comment: No worries - I figured that's what happened because I've done it plenty myself :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just created 12 queries based upon the logic you told. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you can user MAX () KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ) to select the movie_id with the max value of num

```
...
select 
   month, 
   MAX(movie_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST  order by num desc) as movie_id, 
   MAX(num)
from 
 abc
group by month
;
```